# Need help on simplifying cross product of vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors

How do I simplify the following vectors:

a) **a**$\cdot$(**a**$\times$**b**),

b) (**b**-**a**)$\times$**b**   and

c) (**a**-**b**)$\times$(**b**-**a**)

These are my efforts so far. I would appreciate if you could confirm if what I am doing is correct.

> a) **a**$\cdot$(**a**$\times$**b**)= $0$

(Since there are two vectors, i.e. **a** which are equal in the scalar triple product, then its value is zero. Am I applying this property correctly?)

> b) (**b**-**a**)$\times$**b** = (**b**$\times$**b**)-(**a**$\times$**b**)= $0$- **a**$\times$**b**= **b**$\times$**a**

Am I simplifying the above question correctly?

> c) (**a**-**b**)$\times$(**b**-**a**)

(**a**-**b**)$\times$(**b**-**a**)

= (**a**$\times$**b**) - (**b**$\times$**b**) - [(**a**$\times$-**a**) - (-**b**$\times$-**a**)]

=  (**a**$\times$**b**) - $0$ - (**a**$\times$-**a**) + (-**b**$\times$-**a**)

What do I do with all the negative signs?

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull the minus sign in front. So you can simplify earlier:
$$(\mathbf a-\mathbf b)\times(\mathbf b-\mathbf a)=-(\mathbf b-\mathbf a)\times(\mathbf b-\mathbf a)=0$$
The first two are correct